# python convert 10 digits datetimestamp to 13 digit GMT timestamp

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime, gmt

I receive a timestamp from a server like this 1512543958 & when i send back requests in headers i see a 13 digit GMT time stamp like this 1512544485819

By changing the time to local using the code below i get *2017-12-06 12:35:58*

```
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int("1512544474")).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

& when i apply the code below i get *'Wed 06 Dec 2017 07:14:45 GMT'*

```
time.strftime("%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", time.gmtime(1512544485819 / 1000.0))
```

So basically i need a python function that takes the 10 digit date timestamp as argument & returns 13 digit GMT date timestamp

example input 1512544474
expected output 1512544485819

Comment: _when i send back requests in headers i see a 13 digit GMT time stamp like this 1512544485819_, it means that you already have your expected output.

Comment: i see that in chrome network elements , I need a python function that converts the 1512544474 to GMT time stamp 1512544485819

Answer (score 0):

I am using python 2.7

```
import time
import datetime
import time as mod_time
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from datetime import date, timedelta  

today = datetime.now()
yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
today_time = int((mod_time.mktime(today.timetuple())))
yesterday_time = int((mod_time.mktime(yesterday.timetuple())))
today_unixtime = (today_time*1000)
yesterday_unixtime = (yesterday_time*1000)
print("today timestamp =", today_unixtime)
print("yesterday timestamp =", yesterday_unixtime)
```

**Output**

```
('today timestamp =', 1579243097000)
('yesterday timestamp =', 1579156697000)
```

You can check the current time stamp from crome browser console.

new Date(1579243097000)

it will gives you a current date and time.