# How to convert 10 digit timestamp to 13 digit timestamp?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-datetime

In Python 2 how to convert 10 digit timestamp to 13 digit timestamp?

Input:

```
today = datetime.now()
yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
today_unixtime = int((mod_time.mktime(today.timetuple())+today.microsecond/1000000.0))
dt_object = datetime.fromtimestamp(today_unixtime)
print(today)
print("timestamp =", today_unixtime)
print("date =", dt_object)
```

Output:

```
2020-01-17 11:31:40.450943
('timestamp =', 1579240900)
('date =', datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 17, 11, 31, 40))
```

I am getting correct date and time. But when I checked in Chrome browser console,

```
new Date(1579240900)
```

it's given me 50 years back date. While I am converting same timestamp in Python:

Input:

```
 dt_object = datetime.fromtimestamp(today_unixtime)
```

Output:

```
 Mon Jan 19 1970 12:10:40 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Timestamp has to be always 13 digit in year of 2020. Why it's coming as 10 digit? How to convert as 13 digit in Python 2?

I need 13 digit only, my API is taking 13 digit.

This question also asked [python convert 10 digits datetimestamp to 13 digit GMT timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668974/python-convert-10-digits-datetimestamp-to-13-digit-gmt-timestamp) but no answers.

Comment: Multiply it by 1,000? JavaScript handles timestamps in *milli*seconds.

Comment: In fact, *your answer* on the linked question shows multiplying by 1,000, so I'm baffled as to what you're asking here.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Stackoverflow allows to answer your own question if you think it is rellevant for other users. So the OP doesn't really have a question, just wants to share how to solve a problem other people might encounter

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki [self answered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer): 1. must still meet the quality requirements of all posts; and 2. generally don't have the answer posted *an hour later*. Also the OP here has clearly been able to find the previous question, so no signpost is needed, and explicitly says *"but no answers"* despite having posted the same thing there. Maybe that *is* what they were trying to do, but they've gone about it in a baffling way (and it's still just a trivial multiplication, not to mention a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5998245/3001761).

Answer (score 0):

I am using python 2.7

```
import time
import datetime
import time as mod_time
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from datetime import date, timedelta  

today = datetime.now()
yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
today_time = int((mod_time.mktime(today.timetuple())))
yesterday_time = int((mod_time.mktime(yesterday.timetuple())))
today_unixtime = (today_time*1000)
yesterday_unixtime = (yesterday_time*1000)
print("today timestamp =", today_unixtime)
print("yesterday timestamp =", yesterday_unixtime)
```

Output

```
('today timestamp =', 1579243097000)
('yesterday timestamp =', 1579156697000)
```

You can check the current time stamp from crome browser console.

```
new Date(1579243097000)
```

it will gives you a current date and time.